# Mongodo - Sorting only works on a subset of data

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to sort the returned data from an API call based on a mongo aggregation. My issue is that the sorting works if I filter the data to return a few hundred records, but if I return all possible records the sorting doesn't work. My desired goal is to sort by resource name, then trade date.

For example

1. GU_400020 June 2nd
2. GU_400020 June 2nd
3. GU_400020 June 3rd
4. GU_400020 June 3rd
5. GU_400021 June 2nd

Currently I'm getting something like this

1. GU_400020 June 2nd
2. GU_400020 June 2nd
3. GU_400021 June 2nd
4. GU_400021 June 2nd
5. GU_400020 June 3rd
6. GU_400020 June 3rd
7. GU_400021 June 3rd
8. GU_400021 June 3rd

This is my query

```
SD_ActualScheduleAvailability.aggregate([{"$match":{"$and":[{"TRADE_DATE":{"$gte":"2010-06-02"}},{"TRADE_DATE":{"$lte":"2010-06-03"}}],"RS_VERSION":"1","RUN_TYPE":{"$in":["EP1"]}}},{"$project":{"TRADE_DATE":1,"RESOURCE_NAME":1,"PARTICIPANT_NAME":1,"RUN_TYPE":1,"RESOURCE_TYPE":1,"DELIVERY_DATE":1,"DELIVERY_HOUR":{"$convert":{"input":"$DELIVERY_HOUR","to":"int"}},"DELIVERY_INTERVAL":{"$convert":{"input":"$DELIVERY_INTERVAL","to":"int"}},"DELIVERY_TIME":1,"DELIVERY_ORDER":1}},{"$facet":{"items":[{"$skip":0},{"$limit":1000}],"totalItems":[{"$count":"totalItems"}]}},{"$project":{"resultsWithTotal":{"$setUnion":["$items","$totalItems"]}}},{"$unwind":"$resultsWithTotal"},{"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":"$resultsWithTotal"}},{"$sort":{"PARTICIPANT_NAME":1,"RESOURCE_NAME":1,"DELIVERY_DAY":1,"DELIVERY_HOUR":1,"DELIVERY_INTERVAL":1,"DELIVERY_ORDER":1}}],{"allowDiskUse":true})
```

This is the code

```
  $pipeline =  [
    [
      '$match' => $matchPipeline
    ],
    [
      '$project'=> [
        "TRADE_DATE" => 1,
        "RESOURCE_NAME" => 1,
        "PARTICIPANT_NAME" => 1,
        "RUN_TYPE" => 1,
        "RESOURCE_TYPE" => 1,            
        "DELIVERY_DATE" => 1,
        "DELIVERY_HOUR" => ['$convert'=> [ 'input'=> '$DELIVERY_HOUR', 'to'=> 'int']],
        "DELIVERY_INTERVAL" => ['$convert'=> [ 'input'=> '$DELIVERY_INTERVAL', 'to'=> 'int']],
        "DELIVERY_TIME" => 1,
        "DELIVERY_ORDER" => 1,
      ]
    ],
  
    [
      '$facet'=> [
        'items'=>  [[ '$skip'=> $offset ], [ '$limit'=> $limit ]],
        'totalItems'=> [['$count'=> "totalItems"]]
      ]
    ],
    [
      '$project' => [
        "resultsWithTotal"=> ['$setUnion'=> ['$items', '$totalItems']]
      ]
    ],
    [
      '$unwind'=> '$resultsWithTotal'
    ],
    [
      '$replaceRoot'=> ['newRoot'=> '$resultsWithTotal']
    ],

    [
      '$sort' => [
        'PARTICIPANT_NAME' => 1,
        'RESOURCE_NAME' => 1,
        'DELIVERY_DAY' => 1,
        'DELIVERY_HOUR' => 1,
        'DELIVERY_INTERVAL' => 1,
        'DELIVERY_ORDER' => 1,    
      ]
    ],
 
];
```

Sample Document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5eae17810ac25308b9e70f1e"),
    "PID" : "1",
    "RS_VERSION" : "1",
    "TRADE_DATE" : "2010-06-03",
    "RESOURCE_NAME" : "GU_400020",
    "PARTICIPANT_NAME" : "NA",
    "RUN_TYPE" : "EP1",
    "RESOURCE_TYPE" : "APTG",
    "DELIVERY_DATE" : "2010-06-04",
    "DELIVERY_HOUR" : "1",
    "DELIVERY_INTERVAL" : "1",
    "DELIVERY_TIME" : "00:00",
    "DELIVERY_ORDER" : "1",
}
```

If I query for subset of the data, the sorting works as desired for example

```
$matchPipeline["RESOURCE_NAME"] = ['$in'=> ['GU_400020', 'GU_400021']];
```

However if I return all the possible resources, the sorting breaks.

Comment: Can you add sample doc and more explanation too?

Comment: Updated the post @Gibbs

Comment: What problem are you facing with sorting? How do you say that it didn't work? Can you add a reproducible scenario or explanation?

Comment: If I query for subset of the data, the sorting works as desired for example

    $matchPipeline["RESOURCE_NAME"] = ['$in'=> ['GU_400020', 'GU_400021']];

However if I return all the possible resources, the sorting break.

Comment: Break? Does it throw any error? How much size of data you have? How many documents too?